# Problems with Chronicle Map on Windows

Tags: memory-mapped-files, chronicle-map

I am trying to use ChronicleMap for my index structure, this seems to work fine on Linux but when I am running my JUnit test on Windows (which is my development environment),  I keep getting an error:  java.io.IOException: Unable to wait until the file is ready, likely the process which created the file crashed or hung for more than 1 minute.

Here's the code snippet that is problematic:

```
File file = new File(idxFullPath);
        ChronicleMap<Integer, int[]> idx =
                ChronicleMapBuilder.of(Integer.class, int[].class)
                        .averageValue(getSampleIdxList())
                        .entries(IDX_MAX_SIZE)
                        .createPersistedTo(file);
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
[2016-06-17 14:32:47.779] ERROR  main            com.mcm.op.persistence.Persistence                ERR java.io.IOException: Unable to wait until the file is ready, likely the process which created the file crashed or hung for more than 1 minute
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.waitUntilReady(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1520)
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.openWithExistingFile(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1583)
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.createWithFile(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1444)
at net.openhft.chronicle.map.ChronicleMapBuilder.createPersistedTo(ChronicleMapBuilder.java:1405)
at com.mcm.op.persistence.Persistence.initIdx(Persistence.java:131)
at com.mcm.op.persistence.Persistence.init(Persistence.java:177)
at com.mcm.op.persistence.PersistenceTest.initPersist(PersistenceTest.java:47)
at com.mcm.op.persistence.PersistenceTest.setUp(PersistenceTest.java:29)
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it is likely that the process which created the file has crashed, or stopped terminated debugging, or something like that.

If it's ok to have a fresh index from unit test-to-test runs, I recommend to try either delete the file at `idxFullPath` before creating a Chronicle Map, or randomize the mapping file via something like [`File.createTempFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-). In either case [`File.deleteOnExit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit--) could appear to be helpful.

If you want to keep the index between unit test runs and always use the same file at `idxFullPath` for persistence, you could try to use [`builder.createOrRecoverPersistedTo()`](http://static.javadoc.io/net.openhft/chronicle-map/3.8.0/net/openhft/chronicle/map/ChronicleMapBuilder.html#createOrRecoverPersistedTo-java.io.File-) instead of plain `createPersistedTo()` map creation method. However this might slow down the map creation.